# How to compare time in 24 hours format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare two time values with current time in sql server. The time is in 24 hours format. The code I am trying is,

```
declare @StartTime varchar(10)='16:30' 
declare @EndTime varchar(10)='10:10' 
declare @CurrTime varchar(10)='09:30'

 select case when CONVERT(time,@CurrTime) between CONVERT(time,@StartTime)  and CONVERT(time,@EndTime) then 'SUCCESS' else 'FAIL' end
```

and gives the output as 'FAIL'.
Please suggest solution.

Comment: FAIL is correct output

Comment: ...which is correct. Your starttime of 16:30 is after the endtime, so the current time will never be between. You probably just put the wrong values in the variables

Comment: here my Start time is 4:30 PM and end time is next day's 10:10AM. But my time values comes dynamically so the end-time may or may not be of next day so i need to check that and compare accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use datetime datatype and CASE WHEN to check if start date > end date to apply DATEADD to star date in case it is *bigger* then end date:

```
DECLARE @Start nvarchar(5)= N'16:30',
        @End nvarchar(5)= N'10:10',
        @Curr nvarchar(5)=N'09:30'

DECLARE @curdate nvarchar(9) = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),GETDATE(),112)+' '

DECLARE @starttime datetime = @curdate + @Start + ':00.000',
        @endtime datetime = @curdate + @End + ':00.000',
        @currtime datetime = @curdate + @Curr + ':00.000'

SELECT CASE WHEN @currtime between (
     CASE WHEN @starttime > @endtime 
            THEN DATEADD(day,-1,@starttime)
            ELSE @starttime END
                        )  and @endtime THEN 'SUCCESS' 
                                        ELSE 'FAIL' END as result
```

Comment: in my above question, my Start time is 4:30 PM(16:30) and end time is next day's 10:10 AM. But my time values comes dynamically so the end-time may or may not be of next day so i need to check that and compare accordingly.how do i achieve this

Comment: Have you run the sample I provided? I check this with CASE WHEN.